# Android/MySQL: how can I display data based on the department associated with the logged-in user?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am creating an app for staff (users) in a factory. The app needs be logged into by the user. After login, on the next page, the spinner value is based on the user's department. If the user is from the IT department, then the spinner will populate the list of all the 'managers' names' from the IT department. Likewise, when the user is from the Engineering department, then the spinner will populate the list of all managers' names from the Engineering department. The problem is, currently, the spinner will list all managers from all departments.  How can I adjust my code to show only the manager names from the user's department?

php code for user login and list 'mysuggestion':

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbConnect.php';

$response = array();

if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

            if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username', 'password', 'approver'))){

                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $approver = $_POST['approver'];

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT users.id, users.name, users.badgeid, users.position, users.department, users.factory, 
                mysuggestion.reviewer, mysuggestion.title, mysuggestion.year, mysuggestion.month, mysuggestion.suggestionwill, mysuggestion.present, 
                mysuggestion.details, mysuggestion.benefit, mysuggestion.photo, mysuggestion.status, mysuggestion.comment 
                FROM users left JOIN mysuggestion on users.badgeid = mysuggestion.badgeid 
                WHERE users.username = ? AND users.password = ? AND users.approver = ? ORDER BY mysuggestion.id DESC;");
                $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username, $password, $approver);

                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->store_result();

                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

                    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $badgeid, $position, $department, $factory, $reviewer, $title, $year, $month, $suggestionwill, $present, $details, $benefit, $photo, $status ,$comment);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    $user = array(
                        'id'=>$id, 
                        'name'=>$name, 
                        'badgeid'=>$badgeid,
                        'position'=>$position,
                        'department'=>$department,
                        'factory'=>$factory,
                        'reviewer'=>$reviewer, 
                        'title'=>$title, 
                        'year'=>$year, 
                        'month'=>$month,
                        'suggestionwill'=>$suggestionwill,
                        'present'=>$present,
                        'details'=>$details,
                        'benefit'=>$benefit,
                        'photo'=>$photo,
                        'status'=>$status,
                        'comment'=>$comment
                    );

                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
                    $response['user'] = $user; 
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = false; 
                    $response['message'] = 'The data that you insert is not match !!';
                }
            }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
}

echo json_encode($response);

function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

    foreach($params as $param){
        if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

php to populate data from mysql to spinner:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE approver = 'Reviewer';";
require_once('dbConnect.php');

$r = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$reviewer= array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    array_push($reviewer,array(
        'id'=>$row['id'],
        'name'=>$row['name'],
        'badgeid'=>$row['badgeid']
    ));
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$reviewer));

mysqli_close($conn);
```

java code where the spinner located

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion);

    final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView tvTitle = viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText("NEW SUGGESTION");
    abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);

    etTitle = findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etTitle.setText(sharedPref.getString("title", ""));
    etTitle.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            sharedPref.edit().putString("benefit", s.toString()).apply();
        }
    });

    etYear = findViewById(R.id.etYear);
    etMonth = findViewById(R.id.etMonth);
    rgSuggestWill =findViewById(R.id.rgSuggestWill);
    reviewer = new ArrayList<>();

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String mm = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
    int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    etYear.setText(new StringBuilder().append(yy));
    etMonth.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mm));

    spReviewer = findViewById(R.id.spReviewer);
    getData();

    btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

            editor.putString("title",etTitle.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("year",etYear.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("month",etMonth.getText().toString());
            int selectedId = rgSuggestWill.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioButton = findViewById(selectedId);
            editor.putString("suggestionwill",radioButton.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("reviewer",spReviewer.getSelectedItem().toString());
            editor.putString("status", "Pending");
            editor.apply();

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewSuggestion.this, NewSuggestion2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

private void getData(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URLs.URL_SPINNER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

                        //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                        getReviewers(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getReviewers(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding the name of the student to array list
            reviewer.add(json.getString(TAG_NAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spReviewer.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewSuggestion.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, reviewer));
}

//Method to get student name of a particular position
private String getName(int position){
    String name="";
    try {
        //Getting object of given index
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);

        //Fetching name from that object
        name = json.getString(TAG_NAME);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Returning the name
    return name;
}

//Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
private String getCourse(int position){
    String course="";
    try {
        JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
        course = json.getString(TAG_BADGEID);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return course;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("title", etTitle.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewSuggestion.this, DashboardApp.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Welcome. It would be helpful if you could format the code. It helps with readability.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: i know about the password. Will change it after the system go live

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

How about assign a `department` per user login?

Then add a `department_id` in the manager's table

So

Table 1 `Users`
Id | Name | Department Id | Username | Password (encrypted) | etc...

Table 2 `Department`
Department Id | Department Name

Table 3 `Manager`
Id | Manager's Name | Department Id

Then on the Query a new `where` statement should be added:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT users.id, users.name, users.badgeid, users.position, users.department, users.factory, 
                mysuggestion.reviewer, mysuggestion.title, mysuggestion.year, mysuggestion.month, mysuggestion.suggestionwill, mysuggestion.present, 
                mysuggestion.details, mysuggestion.benefit, mysuggestion.photo, mysuggestion.status, mysuggestion.comment 
                FROM users left JOIN mysuggestion on users.badgeid = mysuggestion.badgeid 
                WHERE users.username = ? AND users.password = ? AND users.approver = ?
                AND users.department_id = '{department_id}'
                ORDER BY mysuggestion.id DESC;");
```

A suggestion from me (it will also depends on what's the specifications of the task though)

Store all users and login credentials in a single table and differentiate them by `department` (IT/Engineering/etc...) and `roles` (Users/Manager/etc...)

Comment: i dont want to create many table. any ideas? or need to change at java?

Comment: I think you don't need to change on the java, since on android you will only need the data that is being processed on the server side. You need to change the datasource itself, If you don't want to create new table, I suggest update the query on how you populate the spinner `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE approver = 'Reviewer';";` to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE approver = 'Reviewer' AND departmentId = '{DepartmentID/IT/ENGG}';";`

On this method you will only add new column inside the table. This departmentId will identify the users that are assigned to a specific department